# Custom .NET Data Providers

Tags: .net, ado.net, dataprovider, system.data, dbproviderfactories

Is is possible to use a custom .NET data provider without installing it in the GAC?

Can I reference a custom DLL and register it inside my configuration file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, you can register an implementation of the [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx) class by adding the [following section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your configuration file:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="My Custom Data Provider"
             invariant="MyCustomDataProvider" 
             description="Data Provider for My Custom Store" 
             type="MyNamespace.MyCustomProviderFactory, MyCustomDataProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

The `MyCustomDataProvider` assembly doesn't have to be registered in the GAC but can be deployed together with the application as a [private assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff951638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can refer to the registered data provider programmatically by using the value specified in the `invariant` attribute. For example you could tell ADO.NET to use the `MyNamespace.MyCustomProviderFactory` by specifying `MyCustomProvider` as the `providerName` in the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" 
         providerName="MyCustomProvider" 
         connectionString="MyCustomConnectionString" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In code you can use the same provider name with the [DbProviderFactories.GetFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.getfactory.aspx) method:

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MyCustomDataProvider");
```

where `factory` will be an instance of the `MyNamespace.MyCustomProviderFactory` class.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I don't understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the [fully qualified assembly name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69.aspx) in the `type` attribute?

Comment: I forgot to include the DLL in my start up project.

Comment: You saved me from a lot of trouble. Thank you very much, registering an Sybase SQL Anywhere 16 EF provider works perfectly! Code: `<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere"
           invariant="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.EF6"
           description="SQL Anywhere ADO.NET Provider"
           type="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAFactory, iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.EF6, Version=16.0.0.20764, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f222fc4333e0d400" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>` and setting the correct assembly as dependency. Top!